# sort of revealed

Tags: meaning

*The mystery of what happened to Oliver Hughes was sort of revealed in the finale of the BBC One drama.*

Source: http://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/missing-final-fox-twitter-isnt-4824461

Could you explain to me the meaning of the prhrase "sort of" in the context of the sentence? Does it mean the indication that the ending of the TV series was unsatisfactory as the title of the article suggests?

Comment: It's really hard to figure out the source of your confusion. *Sort of* modifies *revealed*, so...!

Comment: Have you checked any dictionary? Did you find any phrase like **sort of** in dictionary?

Comment: Took me [30 seconds](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sort-of?showCookiePolicy=true). Have to VTC, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Here's what Google says:

> to some extent; in some way or other (used to convey inexactness or vagueness).
>
> "Do you see what I mean?” “Sort of,” answered Jean cautiously.

So your sentence could mean two things.

> The mystery was revealed to some extent.

This means that they explained the mystery, but left a lot of questions unanswered. It was unsatisfying.

> The mystery was revealed in some way.

The mystery was not directly revealed, but some other events in the show made the mystery a little bit more clear.
Although this is a very subtle difference, and not one I would worry about. They both mean "because of the finale, the mystery makes a little bit more sense."

For the article you linked to, I would assume they mean the first one.